# Checkout old commit and make it a new commit

Tags: git

On Git, say I mess up my commits, and I want to make the version 3 commits ago as the new version. If I do `git checkout xxxx`, it creates a new branch and it seems like I can only merge it? Could I make this the new "master version"?

I want:

```
A-B-C-D-E
```

to become

```
A-B-C-D-E-F
```

where F has exactly the same content as C

If I use `git revert xxxx` instead, it seems like it definitely will have conflicts and I need to manually resolve it.

What I really want is just make the old commit at some point the new commit, regardless of what's in my working directory or the latest commit.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: just
`git checkout <commit-hash> . `
don't miss the final dot in the command

Comment: @IbrahimTayseer Yes, but `git rm -r .` is fairly necessary prior to that command, otherwise if there is any file that is present in the newer version but not in the older version is still kept around.

Comment: yes you are right :)

Comment: Not a duplicate, IMO, since this question wants to keep the previous commits in linear history for future reference.  I had the same need, and svick's answer below worked for me, whereas the "duplicate" question was less helpful.

Answer (score 248, accepted):

```
git rm -r .
git checkout HEAD~3 .
git commit
```

After the commit, files in the new `HEAD` will be the same as they were in the revision `HEAD~3`.

Comment: This seem to do what I want. Thanks. If I want to refer to the version by SHA-1 hash, should I be doing git checkout HEAD~XXXXX?

Comment: No, just `git checkout XXXXX`. `rev~n` means *n* revisions before `rev`.

Comment: The dot after HEAD~3 is important.

Comment: @bbuser: is it what, i missed it just now and found another sweet feature.

Comment: this works but I feel like there should be a more elegant way to do this.

Comment: @Gabriel, what's unelegant about this solution? If you want to completely replace the working directory with content from another commit, this looks to me like a straightforward way to do it.

Comment: with a large repo it takes awhile to delete all of the files and then check them all back out.  I feel like git should have a way to revert to an old revision without having to delete everything. But that's just my opinion, this worked well for me and I didn't see a better way when I was looking for alternatives.

Comment: what does 3 represent? 3 from the beginning or most recent?

Comment: @watson `HEAD~3` means “parent of parent of parent of `HEAD`”.

Comment: Is it possible to use a specific commit ID?

Comment: @svick so what would `HEAD~99` represent?

Comment: @Joseph Yes, you can use a commit ID.

Comment: Possible to explain in answer what `rm -r .` does?

Comment: I noticed that this command does not manage files that are moved by `git mv`. File after the rename still exists.

Comment: If you use `git checkout XXXXX .` don't forget the `.` at the end. Same thing with `HEAD~3 .` as @bbuser suggests.

Comment: What is the dot after `HEAD~3` represents ? is this the same thing as BASH current directory ?

Comment: @azzamsa Yes, exactly, it's the current directory.

Comment: Does this loose the history (commits) in between?  I think preserving those is desired.

Comment: @PeteAlvin No, it won't lose any history.

Comment: I used this to keep my log in tact so I could go back to my WIP commit in case I needed to. Using a "dead" branch would also work but this is a feature branch and will be squashed into dev so it's of no consequence beyond that

Comment: I had to `git stash` after `git rm -r .` -- otherwise, this successfully set my working state to a previous commit while still preserving all the intervening commits in linear history, in the same branch -- so useful!

Comment: does merged commit counted as `n` in `HEAD~n`

Comment: Will this also move a branch pointer to the new commit?  Say I checkout `git checkout Wei's_branch` and then run the 3 commands, now `Wei's_branch` will point at `F` instead of `E` or `C`, yes?

Comment: @mraaroncruz the commit 99 before the commit `HEAD` is now pointing to

Comment: @Winny why is `git rm -r` a bad idea?

Comment: For the other git noobs out there, you can also `git stash pop` after you reset to get your local changes back, useful addition to @ultraGentle 's comment

Comment: @Nathanmajicvr.com Thanks. But my teenage daughter was 4 when I made this comment ;)

Comment: @mraaroncruz oh wow

Answer (score 35):

eloone did it file by file with

```
git checkout <commit-hash> <filename>
```

but you could checkout all files more easily by doing

```
git checkout <commit-hash> .
```

Comment: This causes rejection when pushing to origin.

Comment: This works for me. Pushing to origin wasn't a problem.

Comment: so `git checkout <commit-hash>` will detach `HEAD` (push gets rejected), `git checkout <commit-hash> .` should checkout `.` (all changes) from the commit to your working-tree, which you can apply as a new commit.  You can also detach `HEAD` and branch off that commit.  It should then be at `HEAD` for the new branch and you can commit there.  The `.` is important.

Answer (score 34):

It sounds like you just want to reset to C; that is make the tree:

> A-B-C

You can do that with `reset`:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~3
```

<sub>(Note: You said three commits ago so that's what I wrote; in your example C is only two commits ago, so you might want to use `HEAD~2`)</sub>

---

You can also use `revert` if you want, although as far as I know you need to do the reverts one at a time:

```
git revert HEAD     # Reverts E
git revert HEAD~2   # Reverts D
```

That will create a new commit F that's the same contents as D, and G that's the same contents as C. You can `rebase` to squash those together if you want

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. But what if I don't want to do the hard reset since it's already pushed onto a public repository?

Comment: @huggie Ah. Then you probably want to use the revert method

Comment: then git push -f  to force push

Comment: Does this maintain commit "E" and create a new commit, "F"?

Comment: @meetalexjohnson The revert method does; revert makes a new commit that is the opposite of the commit you specified, so they cancel out. The first revert would make F that's the opposite of E, and the second would make G that's the opposite of D, so you end up with the same code you had at C. That's why the second revert is `HEAD~2` instead of `HEAD~1` -- F is the head commit after the first one, so you need to go 2 back to refer to D

Comment: Can I use the commit key (SHA) instead "HEAD~N"?

Comment: And about `git push`? ERROR "fatal: You are not currently on a branch"

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP desires because it looses D-E.

Comment: @PeteAlvin The first version wasn't; the second was. This was discussed in the comments 9 years ago

Comment: FYI Using `reset` will remove your logs for any comments between HEAD and commit you reset to.

Answer (score 23):

This is exactly what I wanted to do. I was not sure of the previous command `git cherry-pick C`, it sounds nice but it seems you do this to get changes from another branch but not on same branch, has anyone tried it?

So I did something else which also worked : 
I got the files I wanted back from the old commit file by file

```
git checkout <commit-hash> <filename>
```

ex : 
    `git checkout 08a6497b76ad098a5f7eda3e4ec89e8032a4da51 file.css`

-> this takes the files as they were from the old commit

Then I did my changes. And I committed again.

```
git status (to check which files were modified)
git diff (to check the changes you made)
git add .
git commit -m "my message"
```

I checked my history with `git log`, and I still have my history along with my new changes made from the old files. And I could push too.

Note that to go back to the state you want you need to put the hash of the commit before the unwanted changes. Also make sure you don't have uncommitted changes before you do that.

Answer (score 12):

`git cherry-pick C`

where C is the commit hash for C. This applies the old commit on top of the newest one.

Comment: `git cherry-pick C` takes the *changes* introduced by C and applies them on top of E. This is not what the OP asked for. He wants to have the files in the exact state that they were in C, which `git checkout` provides.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers so far create new commits that undo what is in older commits.  It is possible to go back and "change history" as it were, but this can be a bit dangerous.  You should *only* do this if the commit you're changing has not been pushed to other repositories.

The command you're looking for is `git rebase --interactive`

If you want to change HEAD~3, the command you want to issue is `git rebase --interactive HEAD~4`.  This will open a text editor and allow you to specify which commits you want to change.

Practice on a different repository before you try this with something important.  The man pages should give you all the rest of the information you need.

Comment: Vote down. 1. the question explicitly asks for keeping older commits, so that might be a reason why other answers attempt to do that. 2. as you said, the commits might have been published and there's no need to introduce comments on what that means with rebasing.