# Git rename from index.lock to index failed

Tags: windows, git, windows-7, github

Using the GitHub Windows client I did a *sync* to pull remote changes to my local machine, but before finishing the sync, I ran out of disk space and the sync failed.  Now I seem to have a bunch of local changes that are actually changes that were being pulled from origin.  I tried to run git pull but got:

```
C:\Users\Tom\SourceLog [master +4 ~26 -0 !]> git pull
Updating b3a86e1..5afd74f
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        SourceLog.Interface/IChangedFile.cs
        SourceLog.Interface/ILogEntry.cs
        ...
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
        Lib/MSBuildExtensionPack/4.0.6.0/Ionic.Zip.dll
        Lib/MSBuildExtensionPack/4.0.6.0/MSBuild.ExtensionPack.dll
        ...
Aborting
```

So now I'm trying to discard the local changes but I'm getting:

```
C:\Users\Tom\SourceLog [master +4 ~26 -0 !]> git checkout -- .
Rename from '.git/index.lock' to '.git/index' failed. Should I try again? (y/n) y
Rename from '.git/index.lock' to '.git/index' failed. Should I try again? (y/n) n
fatal: unable to write new index file
```

How can I clean this up?  (I didn't have any local changes before starting the sync.)

### Update

Can't seem to reset head..

```
C:\Users\Tom\SourceLog [master +4 ~0 -0 !]> git reset head
Rename from '.git/index.lock' to '.git/index' failed. Should I try again? (y/n) y
Rename from '.git/index.lock' to '.git/index' failed. Should I try again? (y/n) n
error: Could not write new index file.
fatal: Could not reset index file to revision 'head'.
```

Comment: Have you freed up some space in the interim? That would be one reason that a rename fails. If that's not the reason rename is failing, you might try deleting `.git/index` (or move it somewhere else, just in case), and try `git reset --hard HEAD` again

Comment: Yeah I cleared a few gigs of space.  Tried moving the index file and discovered a process had a lock on it..

Comment: delete .git/index worked for me . thanks.    
it just recreates it.

Comment: Once GitHub for Windows will use git 2.8.4 (June 2016), you should not see that error anymore. [See my report here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37710754/6309))

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Looks like the following process had a lock on the `.git\index` file:

```
ssh-agent.exe
C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_8810fd5c2c79c73adcc73fd0825f3b32fdb816e7\bin\ssh-agent.exe
```

I killed the process and ran `git reset HEAD` and looks like I'm back to normal now.

Comment: I guess it's not even required to do `git reset HEAD`. It worked for me without that!

Comment: Agreed, I think it's just the ssh-agent.exe process that locks the index file. No need to do anything other than kill it.

Comment: I encountered the same problem, and the process which had a lock for me was Visual Studio Code (or something related to it), because when I shut it down, it worked as expected.

Comment: For me it was explorer.exe although I did not have the actual folder or any sub folder open. Closing all Explorer windows was enough to solve the problem for me.

Answer (score 43):

In my case, this was caused by using the same Git repo from both admin and non-admin command prompts. When last `git pull` was from admin cmd, the `index` was created by it, and then non-admin cmd had insufficient permissions to modify it.

My solution was re-creating the `index` (while keeping the worktree intact):

```
del .git\index
del .git\index.lock
git reset --mixed head
```

Comment: Worked for me by deleting both .git/index and .git/index.lock

Comment: Hi, normally it shouldn't be necessary to specify `--mixed`, as it is the standard already:

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset#git-reset---mixed

Comment: @A.Blesius yes, `--mixed` is the default, but I made it explicit because `reset` command could look scary.

Comment: @DimagogThanks you so much for the tip. In my case: Visual studio in admin mode, and GitKraken in non-admin mode, so I got the message in GitKraken, because of permissions! Thanks!

Comment: After doing this, I was able to `git add .`, but got the error again when doing `git commit`

Answer (score 36):

In my case I had to **close** the **VS code** which I opened with `code .` from a **WSL** Ubuntu terminal.

Comment: exactly what happened to me. but it's still a pain that I have to close vscode to do a git commit.

Answer (score 14):

It can be a real issue, try to run your Terminal as Administrator instead of user. Worked for me

Comment: This was my issue. The place that `.git` was located was in a protected folder

Answer (score 7):

I was seeing this `Rename from '.git/index.lock'...` message when attempting to execute

`git checkout -b my-branch`

The fix for me was to run the command line as `admin`.

Specifically I was using the excellent [cmder](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder) application as a non-admin, which resulted in the rename message appearing. By running [cmder](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder) as an admin, then performing the checkout again, it worked fine.

Answer (score 4):

Git 2.10 (Q3 2016, 4 years later) should improve the situation on Windows

See [commit 05d1ed6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/05d1ed6148305d299693000856e4971e9f642662) (23 Aug 2016) by [Ben Wijen (`Ben`)](https://github.com/bwijen).

> ### `mingw`: ensure temporary file handles are not inherited by child processes
>
> When the index is locked and child processes inherit the handle to
>   said lock and the parent process wants to remove the lock before the
>   child process exits, on Windows there is a problem: it won't work
>   because files cannot be deleted if a process holds a handle on them.
>
> The symptom:

```
Rename from 'xxx/.git/index.lock' to 'xxx/.git/index' failed.
Should I try again? (y/n)
```

> Spawning child processes with `bInheritHandles==FALSE` would not work
>   because no file handles would be inherited, not even the `hStdXxx` handles in `STARTUPINFO` (stdin/stdout/stderr).
>
> Opening every file with `O_NOINHERIT` does not work, either, as e.g. `git-upload-pack` expects inherited file handles.
>
> This leaves us with the only way out: creating temp files with the `O_NOINHERIT` flag. This flag is Windows-specific, however.
>   For our purposes, it is equivalent to `O_CLOEXEC` (which does not exist on
>   Windows), so [let's just open temporary files with the `O_CLOEXEC` flag](https://github.com/git/git/blob/05d1ed6148305d299693000856e4971e9f642662/tempfile.c#L117-L128) and
>   [map that flag to `O_NOINHERIT` on Windows](https://github.com/git/git/blob/05d1ed6148305d299693000856e4971e9f642662/compat/mingw.h#L70-L72).

Answer (score 3):

For me it was this error:

`Rename from 'D:/dev/repo/.git/refs/remotes/origin/my-branch.lock' to 'D:/dev/repo/.git/refs/remotes/origin/my-branch' failed. Should I try again? (y/n)`

Renamed "my-branch" file, retried, and "my-branch.lock" succeed in renaming, not sure if this is correct, but worked. Local changes in both master and my-branch were preserved.

Answer (score 2):

To discard local changes, go

```
git reset HEAD
```

Then checkout your old commit, delete the new one, and pull again.

```
git checkout "hashOld"
git branch -d "hashNew"
git pull
```

Comment: Or read here, this should work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380805/checkout-old-commit-and-make-it-a-new-commit

Comment: Thanks @JamesMcDonnell.  Unfortunately it doesn't look like I can do this either.. (see my update).

Comment: You could delete your .git folder, create a new repo and pull.

Answer (score 1):

I removed `index` and `index.lock` (in the `.git` folder) and ran `git checkout .` to undo the changes and resolved, but if I wanted to commit the changes I would have run `git add -A` after `git commit -m "description"`

Answer (score 1):

I got this error several times in a row when running `git reset HEAD` in a project stored in a Google Drive folder, but after a few minutes the problem went away.

Comment: Ah, also using Google Drive. Seems to go away after a second or two.

Comment: For posterity, version conflicts in Dropbox can also cause this, but it won't go away on its own. In either case, the "conflicted copy" of .git/index just needs to be removed.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue and wanted to post the answer for future searchers. Windows confirmed only. I got this when my git repository was under a directory that requires elevated permissions, AND I was running git from a process(cmd.exe) that did NOT have permissions to write to that folder, thus it could not clear the lock.

The answer is simple, run as admin.

Answer (score 1):

I've answered this on a similar question. Might help others too, quoting the same here:

"For if any windows user stumbles on this:

I faced same issue and it wasn't solved by permissions since I had all the permissions assigned. Removing index.lock didn't help either.

I tried with WSL and it showed this error:

> Another git process seems to be running in this repository.

Based on this I quit every process run by VS Code (that is the IDE I am using) and voila everything back to normal.

Note: Merely closing VS Code didn't help, had to end all processes from task explorer.

On a larger point, try ending all the processes via which you were using git. For me it was just VS Code."

Original answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67615831/13404308

Comment: In my case closing VSCode fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had done a `git pull` as Admin, and my regular user no longer had sufficient permissions.

My solution was to reset ownership to my regular user.

1. Right-click on **.git**, and open ***Properties***.
2. On the ***Security*** tab, click ***Advanced***.
3. In ***Advanced Security Settings***, next to ***Owner***, click ***Change*** (even if it's already correct).
4. In ***Select User***, select the regular user, and click ***Okay***.
5. On the ***Security*** tab, under ***Owner***, you now have a ***Replace owner of subcontainers and objects*** checkbox - Check this and click ***Okay***.

Answer (score 1):

Restart your Source Code editor; killing a Process may work but is not polite_

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with Git. The solution for me was to delete the solution locally through windows explorer, and then re-clone the repository. This removed all the files that were stored locally on my machine, and resulted in the

```
Rename from '.git/..' to '.git/..' failed. Should I try again? (y/n) y
```

going away. After I cloned the respository, I tried my command again(which in my case was GIT COMMIT) and the failure did not reoccur.

The issue came about when I was trying to resolve a merge conflict that was happening after merging a feature branch into the develop branch.

Answer (score 0):

Either kill the process that is locking the file or if it is a new repo, del the .git folder `rm -rf .git` and start again with `git init`

Answer (score 0):

This is caused when antivirus or OS defender (for example Windows Defender) is running. 
The solution: turn off antivirus for several minutes make your add, commit and push. 
Turn on antivirus.
It will work.

Comment: try to highlight the keywords and be clear with the format it will help to reach out your answer for others

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Tortoise Git. I just opened a new Windows Explorer and it fixed this. (For command line Git maybe just open a new shell).

Answer (score 0):

I had seem issue when I was rebase my branch with master. My solution is turn off all solution which are opening and reset hard my branch to origin and rebase again.

Answer (score 0):

`git init` resolved my problem. I was getting below issue.

`Rename from '.git/objects/pack/pack-XXXXX.pack' to '.git/objects/pack/old-XXXXX.pack' failed. Should I try again? (y/n)`

Answer (score 0):

I change project permission

[image]

Then, I exit Code Editor

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot of suggestions. At times, a commit would succeed, but then the error returned. At last, pausing Dropbox sync seems to have done the trick! I have no clue how Dropbox sync could cause this error for longer than a few moments (the time required to sync my 24K `.git/index`).

Answer (score 0):

For my case, it was just Windows Explorer being open and it was opening the directory above the directory that I wanted to rename. After closing Windows Explorer, issue went away immediately.

I was using Bash Git as Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I was using vim on WSL and writing git command on Powershell so I quit vim and then I was able to switch branches

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32419048)

Answer (score 0):

On Windows I resolved this by openeing powershell as admin and doing a `git status` in the folder and closing it.
Then my other terminals/apps were able to use git again without any issues.

Answer (score -1):

I copied (in Windows 10) the whole project to a new folder. Pushed from there to the origin (at that no index problem issued). Then I returned back to the project directory, where the problem occured. Deleted .git directory. Initialized anew (git init). Added to the index (git add . ). Fetched from the remote origin and merged. That's all there is to it.