# Stuck on Git on Windows: Can't checkout, can't stash, can't commit

Tags: git, github

I'm stuck... If I do git stash I get:

```
Fatal: Unable to create /index.lock: File exists. If no other git process is currently running, this probably means a git process crashed in this repository earlier. Make sure no other git process is running and remove the file manually to continue.
```

After manually removing index.lock, I get:

```
Rename from .git/index.lock to .git/index failed. Should I try again? (y/n)
```

git checkout master:

```
 Rename from .git/index.lock to .git/index failed. Should I try again? (y/n)
```

git commit via GitHub:

```
Unable to create a new commit
```

What can I do?

Comment: Consider using [sourcetree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) - a free git client for Windows.

Comment: This should not happen anymore with Git 2.10 (Q3 2016). See http://stackoverflow.com/a/39159518/6309

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Solved it using the universal fix for all software problems: restarted the computer.

Comment: should read: "Solved it using the universal fix for all software problems *in Windows*: restarted the computer."

Comment: also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860751/git-fatal-unable-to-create-path-my-project-git-index-lock-file-exists

Comment: Just start a new CMD terminal solved t for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It happens sometime to me on Windows.

Solution is simple: **close Explorer windows**.

Comment: Or VS if folder opened using WSL

Answer (score 3):

A process certainly had the file locked. You can use [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) from the [SysInternals Suite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062) to find which one : enter part of the path in *> Find > Find Handle or Dll...*. Most of the time, there's no need to restart your computer, it can be as easy as closing an `Explorer.exe` window.

Comment: Thanks man, in my case I've a VM accessing the host folder. Closing VM made the trick ;)