# GIT remote Fetch Failed (screenshot attached)

Tags: git

The fetch was working fine before, now when I fetch from the remote GIT repository i got this following error (please refer screenshot below). even i give "y", i got the same issue

[image]
Is anyone experienced this before? Please help me in this. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Did you already check if it's a problem with a [lock](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635429/git-rename-from-index-lock-to-index-failed)?

Comment: @Jan: Thanks for help. How to check lock is there and how to resolve it?

Comment: For [Windows](http://superuser.com/questions/117902/easy-way-to-find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-or-folder-in-windows) you usually use the `Process Explorer` and for [Linux](http://askubuntu.com/questions/407605/how-to-identify-the-process-locking-a-file) I would use the `lsof` command on CLI

Comment: @Jan: How to unlock it?

Comment: Try to kill the process or simply just try restarting your computer ;)

Comment: @Jan: Which process you want me to kill i.e. git.exe?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your pack file is corrupted.

Pack file is the "git database" where git store all its binary content.
In your case it looks like its "broken" for some reason.

First of all execute `git gc --aggressive` and then verify that the repo is OK with `git fsck`

Comment: Nope, it will not do any harm to your file or repo. its will update the git  internal file system

Comment: same issue if run "git gc --aggressive".

Comment: Seems like your pack file is corrupted. i suggest to do the following:
backup your current folder, clone the repository again then try to add your stuff.

Comment: Do you have local commits that are not pushed yet?

Comment: No i don't have any local commit fortunately

Comment: I deleted my git repo and cloned it again..then only issue is solved..don't  know what is the reason why my pack is failed? update the answer i will mark it as answer....