# git lock keeps coming back on commit rendering GIT useless

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

Ok, so ive never had this problem on GIT before.
My old machine broke a few days back, I am now working of a brand new machine with a fresh windows install. I have set up my GIT through **CMDER**, every time i run git add . I get

```
/.git/index.lock': File exists.

Another git process seems to be running in this repository, e.g.
an editor opened by 'git commit'. Please make sure all processes
are terminated then try again. If it still fails, a git process
may have crashed in this repository earlier:
remove the file manually to continue.
```

so I try and run `rm .git/index.lock`, but when i try and run git add . I get the same message, I removed .git folder from my local then `git init`.

Im still getting the same error, I also notice my task manager runs several **Git for windows** operations, i shut them down, run `rm .git/index.lock` the `git add .`  ... it works !! but then git commit -m"my message" then i get the same index.lock message, how do i fix this, its stopping me working ?

also if I try and run a git command before closing the git for windows task I get

```
rm: cannot remove '.git/index.lock': Device or resource busy
```

Comment: What version of Git are you using? Git 2.10 should be better: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39159518/6309. But I suppose it is a cmder config setting issue.

Comment: Hm, ill check and get back to you. thanks

Comment: using λ git version 2.10.0.windows.1 and tried with git bash, still getting same problem

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your cmder configuration regarding git?

Comment: 5 mins, i may of solved it by uninstalling git in my repo (local) and re-installing