# Git - Error when trying to add files to index

Tags: git

I'm totally newbie on Git. I'm facing an issue when trying to add files to index (cache / staged).

```
Rename from '.git/objects/90/tmp_obj_dsVSGb' to '.git/objects/90/4db657ab28c679e5db9980355b8970972209e8' failed. Should I try again? (y/n)
```

How I can resolve this?

Thank you

Comment: One possibility is that the file currently is opened by another process. A reboot might help :) Then, maybe the resulting file name is too long for your file system. It might help to move the whole project closer to the root (e.g. "C:\"). If that doesn't help, you could check your filesystem for errors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git rename from index.lock to index failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635429/git-rename-from-index-lock-to-index-failed)

Comment: Did you solve this?