# How does Git-Bash for Windows 'rm' work?

Tags: c++, powershell, git-bash

Under some circumstances, the `rm` command in Git-Bash deletes files that can't be deleted in explorer, cmd prompt, PowerShell, or using C++ standard library calls.

Why?

This is perplexing to me because I know there is no magic here and I assume that they are all using the same Win32 API.

For example, I have database snapshots that remain open and cannot be deleted using the other methods described, but are successfully deleted by Git-Bash `rm`:

Explorer delete: "The action cannot be completed because the file is open."

cmd: `del <path>` : "Access is denied"

PS: `Remove-Item -Force -Path <path>` :  "Cannot remove item. Access to the path  is denied."

C++ `remove()` : returns -1

C++ `unlink()` : returns -1

C++ `_unlink()` : returns -1

git-bash `rm <path>` : **success**

The above can be performed repeatedly on different files.

There are other locked files that git-bash `rm` deletes successfully as well (I have used it in the past, not recently and I don't have other specific examples).

However it doesn't always work: In a test application I opened a text file using `fopen()` and none of the methods, including Git-Bash `rm`, could successfully delete it.

So, how does Git-Bash rm work?

Comment: I ma not sure mingw always considered Windows lock status though: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39159518/6309

Comment: Probably because the file is locked by git or something related to git-bash?

Comment: i would think that git-bash itself is locking the file

Comment: In the cases I have seen, git bash is not locking the file. Specifically in the database example provided, the snapshots are locked by the database process and I can delete the snapshots "out from under" the process when logged in as an administrator user that does not own the database process.

Comment: @vonc right: I can only assume that git-bash "rm" is omitting a permissions or lock check that the other applications do not. But how? I have looked at both mingw and git-bash repositories and I haven't been able to find the implementation of "rm" and even the win32 API calls to remove(), unlink(), and _unlink() don't work...

Comment: @apamburn Agreed. You can have a look at https://github.com/git/git/commit/05d1ed6148305d299693000856e4971e9f642662#diff-2d323e09cb6c177bad72feb74df05c8b, and https://github.com/git/git/blob/05d1ed6148305d299693000856e4971e9f642662/tempfile.c#L300-L310 for example.

Comment: I appreciate the links, but none of them quite seem to get at the original question:

How can git-bash for windows `rm <path>` close files opened by a different process that has an open file handle for the files in question, when other windows tools can't? (**not `git rm <file>`, just `rm <file>` on the git-bash terminal**). 

The commits linked appear to refer to opening files with mingw in such a way that they can be later closed, and closing those files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to figure out how this works.

Interestingly, I used Git-Bash's strace utility on it's `rm` command.

It turns out that Git Bash uses CygWin, and the delete routine is found in the [CygWin syscalls.cc file](https://github.com/cygwin/cygwin/blob/master/winsup/cygwin/syscalls.cc) which tries to delete a file in a few different ways.

Eventually it tries to move the file to the Recycle Bin, where it deletes the locked file by opening it with the Windows Driver call NtOpenFile() with a FILE_DELETE_ON_CLOSE flag, then closing it using NtClose().

Not sure if it would be proper to copy CygWin's code into the response here, but details on all of the above can be found in the link provided.