# Builds fail due to timeout during Get Sources step in TFS 2018

Tags: git, tfs

Our TFS build agents are having seemingly random issues with the Get Sources step where the git fetch command hangs and times out after an hour.

The last portion of the logs shows it got everything it needed but decided to just stop until it timed out.

```
2018-04-12T10:00:11.9145204Z Resolving deltas:  97% (123/126)   
2018-04-12T10:00:11.9145204Z Resolving deltas:  99% (125/126)   
2018-04-12T10:00:11.9145204Z Resolving deltas: 100% (126/126)   
2018-04-12T10:00:11.9145204Z Resolving deltas: 100% (126/126), completed with 17 local objects.
2018-04-12T11:00:03.8383793Z ##[debug]Re-evaluate condition on job cancellation for step: 'Get Sources'.
2018-04-12T11:00:04.1196536Z ##[error]The operation was canceled.
2018-04-12T11:00:04.1352781Z ##[debug]System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
   at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.ProcessInvoker.<ExecuteAsync>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Build.GitCommandManager.<ExecuteGitCommandAsync>d__33.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Build.GitCommandManager.<GitFetch>d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Build.GitSourceProvider.<GetSourceAsync>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Build.BuildJobExtension.<GetSourceAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.JobExtensionRunner.<RunAsync>d__20.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.StepsRunner.<RunStepAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
2018-04-12T11:00:04.1352781Z ##[section]Finishing: Get Sources
```

We have 4 build agents setup and usually one or two have this problem each night during builds.

When I look into the agent's directory and run a git status command, I get a message saying:

```
Rename from 'C:\BuildAgent1\_work\1\s\.git\index.lock' to C:\BuildAgent1\_work\1\s\.git\index' failed. Should I try again? (y/n)
```

Entering 'y' just causes that message to repeat. Looking into the .git/ folder, there is no index.lock file present.

Issuing another build manually and the build gets past the Get Sources step without issue.

Why are the builds hanging after fetching everything?

Comment: Just try to set **clean** to `true` and **Clean options** select `Sources directory` under Get Sources, then check if that works.

Comment: I'll give that a shot and see how the builds work more reliably. Some of the build definitions already have the clean option set to true and has the sources directory option set which have failed previously.

Comment: You can also try to delete the `index` and `index.lock` file directly on agent machine under the `.git` folder (Something like `C:\Agent\_work\2\s\.git`). Then check it again. You can also reference [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635429/git-rename-from-index-lock-to-index-failed) for the troubleshooting.

Comment: The thing is, there was no index.lock file. But from looking at today's nightly builds, this particular problem did not happen after changing all definitions to clean, so thanks for that suggestion. I ran into another (probably unrelated) issue, which I am engaged with microsoft's support at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the solution for this issue is cleaning the sources directory.

- Set **Clean** to `true` and **Clean options** select `Sources directory` under **Get Sources** step.
- Alternatively you can delete the source folder manually on agent
  machine. (e.g.: `C:\Agent\_work\2\s\`, basically delete the `.git`
  folder will resolve the issue `C:\Agent\_work\2\s\.git`)

[image]