# git diff --name-only giving error when run from PowerShell Script

Tags: git, powershell

I am trying to get modified files in PowerShell using script. I am using `git diff --name-only` command to do so. The issue is when I run this command inside PowerShell script ps1, it gives following error. When I run it directly in PowerShell, it is working fine. The command still gives output but there is Interrupt which needs user action.

```
Error - Rename from 'E:/o18/src/.git/index.lock' to 'E:/o18/src/.git/index' failed. Should I try again? (y/n)
```

I tried to find which process has lock on index.lock file using ProcessExplorer but it is not giving any process.

Simplified code:

```
function Get-ModifiedGitFiles
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param()

    $files = @()
    $time = Measure-Command {
        $CommitID = git rev-parse HEAD
        $result = git diff --name-only $CommitID
        Write-Host $result
    }
    return $files
}
```

Comment: "Get-CurrentRepoHeadCommit: The term 'Get-CurrentRepoHeadCommit' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program." :)

Comment: It seems unlikely that running interactively vs. via a script would make a difference. However, per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43107413/45375) it can make a difference whether you run _with elevation_ or not.

Comment: I'm afraid it's a bug of the new versions. After upgrading Git to the latest version, I always encounter with this issue occationally.

Comment: @ElpieKay, you mean Git v2.42.0? Does it only happen in PowerShell, or also from `cmd.exe`/ batch files?

Comment: @mklement0 In `git-bash`. I can't check its version on my working computer now as I'm on vacation.