# How to reset in Gitlab with protected branches

Tags: git, gitlab

Somebody messed up the git repository with his merge. The only choice is to get back and throw away all changes before his commit. The problem is that the `develop` branch is protected from push and we have to use merge requests. I forked new branch from the last commit before his merge and pushed it to GitLab. Gitlab complains that the MR is six commits behind the target branch and it wants to merge only new commit in my branch. It did not reset.

I think that the only way is to remove the branch protection and fix it there directly. Am I right?

Comment: You *could* also consider reverting the merge (sometimes tricky but doesn't need lifting branch protection and rewriting history). (There's also a possibility with `git commit-tree` discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59413307/git-revert-to-previous-commit-as-a-new-commit-using-tree-hashes) and [there](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20190513-00/?p=102490))

Comment: Well, he moved a lot of files around, then renamed directories, did some fixes inside new directories .. Undo commit creates hundreds of conflicts.

Comment: If you can lift protection, yes it will be way easier. Be sure to communicate with everyone involved of course, but you seem to know that already.

Comment: This commit-tree is a kind of magic. I rather stick with KISS approach. Thanks.