# "HEAD detached from": how to get back to master and apply the changes commited to submodule?

Tags: git

I am new to using submodules in Git.

I have (somehow) checked out all the submodules, made some changes in one of them, added changes, and commited (one file added, another file modified). I did not `git push` the changes yet.

When I execute `git status` I get "HEAD detached from..." message.

Where did my commit end up in?

I would like to get back to `master` as I am used to. And I would like to apply the changes to master.

How do I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my GIT Submodule HEAD detached from master?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770545/why-is-my-git-submodule-head-detached-from-master)

Comment: In addition to reviewing the info from @alex. I would open gitk and record your current sha. Then `git checkout <branch>` and `cherry-pick your commit git cherry-pick <sha>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reconcile detached head and origin/master? Already checked out old hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48797325/how-to-reconcile-detached-head-and-origin-master-already-checked-out-old-hash)