# Adding a Commit to git while HEAD is not pointing to the last Commit ( Tip )

Tags: git

By wrong, I checked out the `master` branch to a specific commit and added a new commit while `Head` is not pointing to the `Tip` (last commit)
now I  got a  "detached head"

What does that mean? and How can I move that Commit to be the last commit (`Tip`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reconcile detached head and origin/master? Already checked out old hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48797325/how-to-reconcile-detached-head-and-origin-master-already-checked-out-old-hash)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# create a branch at the current commit
git branch temp

# get back on master
git checkout master

# bring the lost commit back
git merge temp
```