# Why is the dot imporant? What does it do? 'git checkout HEAD~3 .'

Tags: git, github

In this post..

[Checkout old commit and make it a new commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380805/checkout-old-commit-and-make-it-a-new-commit)

```
git rm -r .
git checkout HEAD~3 .
git commit
```

I accidentally ran `git checkout HEAD~3` rather than `git checkout HEAD~3 .`

What problem will this cause me? What is the purpose of the dot? If it is a problem, how do I fix it?

Comment: `.` represents the current folder. What problem are you having?

Comment: See `git help checkout`. Without the `.`, you have the `git checkout [-q] [-f] [-m] [<branch>]` form. With the `.`, you have the `git checkout [-f|--ours|--theirs|-m|--conflict=<style>] [<tree-ish>] [--] <pathspec>...` form.

Comment: This may be a good reason to stop using `checkout` and start using the newer and equivalent `switch` and `restore` commands instead. With the new commands it's not possible to accidentally make this mistake. Although it was harmless in your case, going the other way could sometimes ruin your day.

Comment: Side note, a better way make a new commit which reverts the top X most recent commits, is [probably here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1895095/184546).

Comment: I'm sure there are more duplicates, but `.` does not search well in google...